# Setting Google Colab to use Theano as Backend

Tags: keras, theano, google-colaboratory

I'm following an online tutorial which uses Theano as backend. I am using Google Colab which defaults to Tensorflow as backend.

How can we switch to using Theano as backend? Thanks

Comment: Did you find a workaround for the backend change on Google Colab as I need the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help,

```
import os
os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "theano"
import keras.backend
keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```

Comment: I get the following error:
`AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'`

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm facing the same error @JorgeM.LondoñoP.

Comment: I use keras.backend.common.set_image_dim_ordering('th')

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution here doesn't work anymore due to `keras` version. Downgrade to `2.2.4` and run the above code:

```
!pip uninstall keras
!pip install keras==2.2.4

import os

os.environ["KERAS_BACKEND"] = "theano"
import keras.backend
keras.backend.set_image_dim_ordering('th')
```